# JOIN table showing no results

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to join two tables together but with no luck. I'm not sure why it's returning 0 results. Thank you for any help pointing me in the right direction

```
 $query = "SELECT contacts.account, contacts.lname, contacts.fname, contacts.title, contacts.company, contacts.address, contacts.addresstwo, contacts.city, contacts.state, contacts.zip, contacts.cell, contacts.officenum, contacts.email_status, nameinfo.tags, nameinfo.email
FROM nameinfo
INNER JOIN contacts
ON nameinfo.email=contacts.email";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $masterlist[] = array(
  'click_through' => 'person.php?email='. $row['email'],
    'account' => $row['account'],
    'lname' => $row['lname'],
        'fname' => $row['fname'],
  'tags' => $row['tags'],
   'title' => $row['title'],
        'company' => $row['company'],
  'address' => $row['address'],
  'addresstwo' => $row['addresstwo'],
   'city' => $row['city'],
        'state' => $row['state'],
  'zip' => $row['zip'],
  'email' => $row['email'],
   'cell' => $row['cell'],
        'officenum' => $row['officenum'],
  'mail_status' => $row['email_status']
      );
  }
  echo json_encode($masterlist);
```

the nameinfo table has an email address and a contact tag associated with an email. There can be multiple rows with the same email but each row gets a different tag. The contacts table has the user information (first name, last, name, etc). I want the pull the nameinfo table and fill it with information from the contacts when email matches email.

```
nameinfo
email              tags
abc@gmail.com      postcard
abc@gmail.com      business
xyz@gmail.com      postcard

contacts
email              lname         fname        company
abc@gmail.com      Smith         John         Printing Expert Inc
xyz@gmail.com      Doe           Jane         Businesss Cards Inc
```

I'm trying to combine information so I get this result in to an HTML table.

```
abc@gmail.com     postcard       Smith       John       Printing Expert Inc
abc@gmail.com     business       Smith       John       Printing Expert Inc
xyz@gmail.com     postcard       Doe         Jane       Business Card Inc
```

Comment: what happens when you run this directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: Nothing it says "Loading" then the loading bar disappears and it stays on the execute tab.

Comment: try this:
`SELECT *
FROM nameinfo
LEFT JOIN contacts
ON nameinfo.email=contacts.email`

Comment: Same thing I run the query through phpmyadmin and all I get is a yellow "Loading Bar" then nothing. I'm getting a request timed out when I execute the query through my php file.

Comment: LIMIT doesn't take 'from' and 'to' arguments!?!?! It takes 'from' and 'number of rows from `from`'. Also, please note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty uch meaningless.

Comment: The limit that's there is just saying show the first 50,000 rows. $from and $to are just numbers  "LIMIT 0,50000"

Comment: OK. I give up. So, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. Provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. Provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Strawberry... I updated my post to show you what I'm trying to achieve. I also deleted the LIMIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to give you the desired result from the DB (provided that there's at least one entry in each table for the same email address):

```
SELECT email, tags, lname, fname, company FROM nameinfo JOIN contacts USING (email)
```

If it doesn't, then you're not providing enough information. How big are the tables? What are the indices?

Comment: The CONTACTS table is 22538, Tags table is roughly 45000. Each row has an auto_increment as the primary. Every row on both tables has an email address and if there is an email address in the TAGS table there is a row in the contact with the same email.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM nameinfo JOIN contacts USING (email)"; <--- that worked thank you for the help

Comment: @Billy: Also: make sure to have an index on the `email` columns.